# Notice: Undefined variable: charset

Tags: php

In localhost My php code is generating a notice

> Notice: Undefined variable: charset in fullpath/script.php on line 4 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0005252616{main}( )..\demo-user-words.php:0 ">

What does it mean? How to solve it?

Any Idea

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Comment: sorry for mistakely repeating the question, bt i tried to find the solution. Bt i cnt so i ask the question.

Comment: thanks man its really apricated